# Can I deploy code from DevOps to Azure Web running on Linux Container?

Tags: azure, powershell, docker, azure-web-app-service, devops

I have a Web app running on Linux which is deployed from Docker Container.
Container comes from Azure container registry and was defined when I created the web app.
When I try to set my release pipeline to deploy to this web app, it doesnt offer me this choice.
When I set my subscription and Web app on Linux, I only see web apps that are deployed from code. My web app from docker container is not in the list in the App Name select:

[image]

I tried to do this manually using Azure PowerShell. I have set up local connection and trying to test the deploy but it doesnt work.
I have downloaded the repository locally as a zip file and I am trying to deploy it from this local zip file to the Web app on Azure. I try to deploy it from Powershell:

```
$webapp = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName "MyResourceGroup" -Name "my-container-app"
$path = 'C:\temp\repository.zip'
Publish-AzWebApp -WebApp $webapp -ArchivePath $path -Force
```

I am using [Publish-AzWebApp command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/publish-azwebapp?view=azps-3.8.0).
This command goes without an error, I also tried without -Force parameter, and with -AsJob parameter.
Everytime the command is executed successfully, but when I check my web app there is nothing deployed there. If I try this exact procedure with web app that is not from container, but from code than it works. By code/container I mean this setting that you choose when creating web app:
[image]

Currently I am using docker image that is also used by Azure as default so it should be the same Debian. I need to use it because I want to set some things differently in my web app, so I want to have my own system on web app, but deploy code from Devops to it.
However it seems that this type of web app is not supperted for deploy - nether from Devops gui, nor from Azure CLI. Can I somehow deploy my code on a web app that is running on my custom docker image?

PS: One option is to use the agent in Devops pipeline, compile a docker image from it and publish it with my code to the Azure container repository, from which it can be used form my web app. Problem is that you can only choose from 2 Ubuntu versions as an agent for build pipeline and I dont want that.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirements, first of all, you need to know the Web App on Linux and Web App for Container are two different resources, so it does not list your app deployed from the docker image. And second, when you use the docker image, it means you need to create a new image when your code change. So it does not support that create the Web App from the docker image and then publish the code from the DevOps.

The option that you think is right. Don't worry about the OS, you can use the Azure CLI command to create the docker image and push it to the Azure Container Registry directly:

```
az acr build -t image_name:tag -r acr_name source_code_path
```

And then deploy the image from the ACR to the Web App. In this way, the DevOps agent just use to run the task, not for the creation of the docker image.

Comment: Thank you, I used this scenario to build and deploy it to ACR and it seems that now I am on right track